# Reset Arduino Nano V3

Tags: arduino, reset

I work on Arduino Nano V3, but when i upload programs with ROM function, my adruino enter in infinite loop and broke the possibility to uploads new programs :s

I try something :

```
- Push reset button on board => no result
- Only connect TX  / RX => no result
```

Solutions ?

I've 2 reset pins, but don't know how to use it. I'have only one arduino.

Error message :

```
avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : \\.\COM4
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
```

.

```
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: 
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done
```

Thank you.

Thank's for your help

Comment: What errors are you getting? There is no question here....

Comment: He wants to know how to do a full reset of the chip, I think.

Comment: Get a AVR ISP device. Reflash the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another arduino hanging around, you can use that as an ISP programmer.

Here's how: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Following that tutorial will force the chip to reset via the ISP interface, as they are programmed with system interrupts.

*I had that happen to me when I was working with the micro and using libraries with no time compensation, the chip emulates a USB device on windows and so when it was plugged in, the device would loop as fast as the core could go and find it's self not being able to recieve the reset pull or a char to program it.